# How to add row name in tab delimited file with header in Linux

Tags: linux

I am dealing with a table file with thousands line and header.
But I have to add row name (row name represent row number) in each line. 
How could I do this in linux?

I can done this with excel, but there are too many files so I wish I could write down linux command to deal with it.

My file looks like this.

```
parameter1 parameter2 paramter3
1.2 1.3 1.4
2.1 2.1 1.5
1.5 1.6 2.1
....
```

And I would like to added row name as following:

```
sim parameter1 parameter2 paramter3
AM_1_arp 1.2 1.3 1.4
AM_2_arp 2.1 2.1 1.5
AM_3_arp 1.5 1.6 2.1
....
```

How could I done these with linux commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {i=0} {print "AM_" i++ "_arp " $0}' <file> | sed 's/AM_0_arp/sim/g'
```

I'll just add your string of choice with a counter in between to the beginning of each line and then replace the first instance with sim for the header.

Answer (score 3):

With awk:

```
 awk 'NR==1{print "sim "$0;next}{print "AM_"NR-1"_arp "$0}' yourfile
```

That says:

1. If this is the first line (header row) `NR==1` then print "sim " plus the entire line: `print "sim "$0;`
2. Go to the next line skipping the rest of the program `next`
3. For any other line encountered print "AM " plus the line number `NR` plus "_arp " then the entire line `$0`.

If you have many files in a directory for which you need to do this, you can reference them by wildcard and you can redirect the output inside of awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{print "sim "$0 > FILENAME"_out";next}{print "AM_"NR-1"_arp "$0 > FILENAME"_out"}' ./yourfile*
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the code, and it does print row name.
But it seems NF do not work, all row name are the same "AM_10_arp"

Comment: That is odd. I've never run into NF not working. I'm glad to see that the `i++` counter version is doing the trick though!

Comment: I tried this version too and I also get a weird numbering like: AM_3_arp, AM_3_arp, AM_2_arp, AM_2_arp for some reason. I tried it with GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: @JNevill NF is number of fields, did you mean NR?

Comment: @oguzismail OMG THANK YOU!. Clearly I need more coffee. Write this schlock for years and I still mess it up.

Comment: @Bing-HongHuang I just updated to use `NR` (line number) instead of `NF` (number of fields). Very sorry for that miss. I believe the updated answer should run for you as-is.

Comment: @JNevill
Thank you for kindly reply, it works, but it begin with AM_2_arp not AM_1_arp

Comment: @Bing-HongHuang You can just change it from `NR` to `NR-1` in that second `print`. I will update. (sorry for the wait)